# Can I configure "allow posting by mail" through google setting API?

Tags: google-apps, google-groups-api, google-groups-settings

How I configure "allow posting by mail" through google setting API?

the only configuration I found is:

"whoCanPostMessage": "ALL_IN_DOMAIN_CAN_POST",

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, there is not a setting in the [Groups Settings API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/groups-settings/v1/reference/groups) that allows you to toggle whether or not posts can come to the group via email. The closest setting is `apps:allowWebPosting` which allows you to toggle posting via the Group's Web UI.